# Game Center login view controller only presenting when I use deprecated authenticateWithCompletionHandler: method

Tags: authentication, ios6, game-center, gamekit

I realize this following method is deprecated in iOS 6, but it still works.  It just issues a deprecated method warning.  From my `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:(^(NSError *error) {
            if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated) {
                self.gameCenterAuthenticationComplete = YES;

                if (! self.currentPlayerID || ! [self.currentPlayerID isEqualToString:localPlayer.playerID]) {
                    self.currentPlayerID = localPlayer.playerID;
                }
            } else {
                self.gameCenterAuthenticationComplete = NO;
            }
        })];
```

So I'm trying to use this method instead, which is the proper way to do it in iOS 6.  I get the alert to show up, but I cannot get the `Game Center login view controller` to come up:

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
            if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated) {
                self.gameCenterAuthenticationComplete = YES;

                if (! self.currentPlayerID || ! [self.currentPlayerID isEqualToString:localPlayer.playerID]) {
                    self.currentPlayerID = localPlayer.playerID;
                    }
                } else {

                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                              initWithTitle:@"NOT AUTHORIZED"
                                              message:@"This game requires Game Center to create matches."
                                              delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alertView show];
                    self.gameCenterAuthenticationComplete = NO;
                }
        })];
    }
    return YES;
```

The first approach--the deprecated way--immediately brings up the `Game Center login view` when the app opens and detects that the user is not signed in to GC.  It also displays the **"Welcome Back"** popover thingy when the user is logged in.

The second approach--the iOS 6 way--does not display the `GC login screen`, as I stated above, but it does say **"Welcome Back"** if the user is already logged in to GC via the GC app.

For information, I've tried this **on my iPhone 5 (6.0.1), my iPad mini (6.0.2), and on the simulator (6.0).**

Anyone have any idea why this would happen?  How do I manually display the `GC login view controller` in the second approach, if that's what I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

You have to display the login screen yourself. The call to setAuthenticationHandler sets up the screen and gives you a pointer to it in 'viewController'. You just say

```
[self presentViewController:viewController];
```

This lets you show the login screen when it makes the most sense in the context of your game.

BTW... you are not checking for an error. Errors are common (for example, no network access).